# Font issue with matrix in rdl file - Power BI paginated report

Tags: matrix, fonts, powerbi, rdl, powerbi-paginated-reports

In Power BI Paginated Report we have selected the font type for the rows in the Matrix.

[image]

When we export the Excel file from Power BI the matrix is collapsed like this, and the font is the right one for the first level:

[image]

But, when we expand the other levels, we are getting this :

[image]

What could be happening ?